Vscodium not recognizing wx/wx.h file
I installed vscodium and wx/wx.h in my macbook pro using homebrew to install both.
I'm trying to start a gui project using wx/wx.h, but every time I try to include the header file, I get an error issue via the clangd intellisense that says it can't find the wx/wx.h file. But the path that is specified does have the wx/wx.h file. The path listed also has the setup.h file, so I'm very confused. Attached is a screenshot of the vscodium issue.
If anyone has encountered this issue before and resolved it, please let me know. If anyone has an idea of how to resolve this. Please let me know too. Your help would be hugely appreciated.enter image description here
The thing is the code compiles no problem, but I want to get rid of the annoying error cause it keeps the intellisence system from being of real help.
First to clarify. For the intellisense of my vscodium. I'm using clangd. There was no .vscode directory and I created it. Then I created a c_cpp_properties.json file and put it inside the .vscode directory. The contents of the c_cpp_properties.json file are:
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/include/wx",
            "/usr/include"
        ],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/System/Library/Frameworks",
            "/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++20"
    }
],
"version": 4

That didn't work. I think that vscodium's clangd is using something aside from the c_cpp_properties.json file to try an resolve this.
I also tried manually moving the wx/ directory to a different location and using that, but it failed as well.

You set /usr/local/include/wx and include wx/wx.h. Now try to combine them and /usr/local/include/wx/wx/wx.h and ensure the resulting path is valid.

@I'mLearning, I dont know what Vscodium is - I presume it is VSCode. I also not sure why you are using HB instead of building the library yourself - it is quick and easy. But OK. To answer your question - please show the content of /usr/local/incluude and /usr/local/include/wx. Please DO NOT POST SCREENSHOT!!!! Cut and paste the content from the Terminal in the OP as an EDIT

Very common error, you are saying directory wx twice, once in #include and once in includePath. Change "/usr/local/include/wx", to "/usr/local/include",

c_cpp_properties.json is a configuration file used by a diferent C/C++ vscode plugin, vscode-cpptools (which is proprietary and probably doesn't work with vscodium). Clangd (which does work with vscodium) has a different method of configuration, you can read about it and follow the steps here: https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup

@imlearning, working with wx requires 2 include folders. Please follow multiple tutorial on the web and the official docs. If something is not clear - ask the specific question.

@ImLearning, also building the library is pretty straightforward. I suggest to download the source code, build it, build minimal sample, see what is needed and then come back  here if something is not clear.
